# Ubuntu 16.04 not switching automatically to headphones

Tags: headphones, pavucontrol

every time the OS starts, the headphones are detected in pavucontrol, however I need to select them manually. Is there a way to automatize this process?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/859732/sound-configuration-is-lost-on-restart