# Output channel for audio resets after every reboot

Tags: sound

I use my "Line Out - Built-in Audio" for my speakers, but for some reason, every time I reboot my computer, it changes by default to "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio".

The funny thing is that, if I unplug and re-plug my speaker connector, the channel changes by itself to "Line Out" without me having to do anything.

What could I do so that I can stop doing this annoying step every day?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Answer (score 6):

You can have pulse audio stay on the last selected output source no matter what:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Find this line:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

and change it to:

```
# load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

An additional step is needed as listed in:

- [Sound configuration is lost on restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859732/sound-configuration-is-lost-on-restart)

We need to add the line:

```
set-sink-port <name|index>  analog-output-headphones
```

The `name` or `index` of the active sink, and available ports can be displayed with `pactl list sinks`. The way I spelled `analog-output-lineout` may be incorrect.

Save the file and exit.

Restart pulse audio with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

In your sound settings select "Line Out" and it will always stay connected even if you physically unplug it.

Comment: It did not work :/

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent I've revised the answer with a similar problem's solution.

Comment: I don't have a `set-sink-port` command. In the `default.pa` there is a `load-module module-switch-on-connect`. Could that be relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure. I must confess I'm not an expert and struggle with pulseaudio and alsa myself many times.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple audio devices connected:

- Internal sound card
- Speakers via HDMI monitor
- USB Mic and headphone adapter

As suggested by Enrique in a comment to WinnEunuuchs2Unix answer, I commented out the line `load-module module-switch-on-connect` in my `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and it solved my problems of having the primary audio device change every boot.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me and i managed to solve it with the help of [this arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples). I set the desired devices as current through settings first, then did `pacmd list-sources` and `pacmd list-sinks` to get the names of current input and output devices (the ones with "*" after index). Then opened `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and found lines that were commented out (you can simply add those if they are not already present):

```
# set-default-sink output
# set-default-source input
```

I uncommented them and replaced `output` and `input` with the acquired device names. Restarted pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k` and devices stayed the way i wanted!