# I have no audio from Firefox, but do from other programs (Zoom, VLC, Chromium)

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I upgraded a couple of weeks ago, and in the process I regained a problem I'd previously fixed. Now my audio output resets itself on each reboot. Irritating. But I've been living with it.

Today, two things happened. I'm not sure which one caused the problem.

1. I've moved back to my parents' house to house-sit for a couple of days. I brought my computer, but not my monitor (which contains speakers). So I'm now using "Speakers - Built-in audio" or "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - C-1U" (which seem identical) instead of the HDMI output I usually use. (The preferred output device it keeps resetting to is "Speakers - C-1U", which is actually a USB microphone, and does nothing when selected as a speaker.)
2. I tried to fix the annoying constant reset by commenting out the line `load-module module-switch-on-port-available`, as recommended in https://askubuntu.com/a/1171617/652. I have since undone that again, with no apparent effect.

All other programs I've tried still have working audio, but Firefox does not. It's not disabled in sound settings.

[image: Sound settings, showing Firefox audio at max volume]

Comment: Is firefox installed via snap? if so, have you checked the `audio-playback` interface (listed in the terminal using `snap connections firefox`)?

Comment: It is a snap, and has been since the upgrade. It looks correct (at least, it looks the same as VLC, which is working). `audio-playback  firefox:audio-playback  :audio-playback  -` matches `audio-playback  vlc:audio-playback  :audio-playback  -`