# Pulseaudio - Configs updated back to default on restart

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, my PC's front audio port isn't working. I have got Pulseaudio installed, update the configurations to `Analog Stereo Duplex` or `Analog Stereo Output` then the sound will be available, even though those options were marked as `(unplugged)(unavailable)`. However, if I do a reboot, the configs converted back to default which requires a few more clicks to make the sound available which is really annoying.

I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/859737/947040) answer but it did not work. After updating the `default.pa` file, Pulseaudio was unable to restart, kept saying `can't find card by this name or index` for both name and index. Using index was indeed make the sound available on startup but volume was fixed, and was not able to change, Pulseaudio refused to start either.

So is there any workaround I could make to save a few clicks on every startup? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering "pulseaudio --start" into the Startup Applications function, click Add and next time you boot up, a speaker icon should appear in the top bar and you should have sound